# Node JS upload, manage and download multiple images for different users

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, multer

Found several tutorials on uploading multiple images using multer, but failed to find how to manage those files(like naming without overwriting) for particular user and get/retrieve in frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Hi for naming file with multer you can do like this:

```
import multer from 'multer';
import mime from 'mime';
let storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './dist/client/assets/uploads/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(16, function (err, raw) {
      cb(null, raw.toString('hex') + Date.now() + '.' + mime.extension(file.mimetype));
    });
  }
});

let uploader = multer({
  storage: storage
});
router.post('/upload', uploader.array('upload', 10), ctrl.uploadFile);
```

you can store the path in DB and you can get it like this :

```
for (let i=0 ; i<req.files.length; i++){
 let pathFile = req.files[i].path;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Marwen, what about storing and retrieving ? any idea how we store path and return to frontend?